axe-core accessibility library reports incorrect colour values
I started getting unusual colour contrast reports from axe-core.js. The weird part is the colours do not match any of the css rules for foreground or background for the page.
I changed the method to call the axe validator and defer when I called the axe library  in hopes that it axe was being tricked by the page still rendering fonts and colours, but this did not help. the code I am using is below:
Has anyone else had a similar situation ?


window.onload = () => {
  document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
    requestIdleCallback(() => {
      console.log('Page is fully loaded, fonts are ready, and browser is idle.');
axe
  .run()
  .then(results => {
if (results.violations.length) {
  throw new Error('Accessibility issues found');
}
  })
  .catch(err => {
console.error('Something bad happened:', err.message);
  });
    });
  });
};




Suggest converting the StackSnippet to just a formatted code block if it's not meant to be runnable
